# Use Ionic Portal inside Ionic Framework React Native Apps? (Webview inside Ionic App without covering up IonTabBar)

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, inappbrowser, ionic6

I have a use case where I would like to leverage some existing pages from a Shopify powered store inside an Ionic Framework v6 React iOS / Android App (on web we will simply redirect to the appropriate subdomain).  Unfortunately, [Shopify has their iFrame options set to Deny](https://community.shopify.com/c/api-announcements/loading-storefront-in-iframe-x-frame-options/td-p/420775) so using an iFrame is not an option.

[Image of where the Shopify Store should show up in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plam6.png)

I've looked at the various flavors of [inAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#sample), and while this allows me to show the page, its a pretty jarring non-native app experience.  What I really want is an Ionic React Component for Native that will allow me place a webview under my control constrained to a certain viewport of the page.

Ionic Portals are targeted at Native developers with fully native code bases but actually show this use case on the [home page](https://ionic.io/portals):

[Image of Ionic Portal webview inside Native Tab Bar Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1C9i.png)

**I know portals are pretty new and I haven't seen any documentation about this but is it possible to use them inside of an Ionic React App to accomplish the behavior I want (or something in inAppBrowser or another plugin that I've missed?)**